# How to perform this c# instantiation and method usage in 1 line?

Tags: c#

I'm pretty anal when it comes to making my code succinct.

```
SVNLock lock_obj = new SVNLock(lock_file);
lock_obj.Execute();
```

Is there any way I can do it

Thanks!

Comment: Note: Execute is not a static method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does Execute return?

If the constructor does not return anything special, you can do `new SVNLock(lock_file).Execute();`.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, although I'm not sure I recommend doing things this way.

Comment: Sure, but if Execute doesn't return a reference to `this`, the new instance immediately goes out of scope and may be garbage-collected.  This may be problematic if you need to `Dispose` of it, instead.

Comment: @Gabe && Steven Sudit: What the both of you said.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use the `lock_obj` variable anywhere else, you can write

```
new SVNLock(lock_file).Execute();
```

If you do use the variable later, there is nothing you can do, unless you edit the `SVNLock` class and make `Execute` return the instance  (This is called a [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)).  If you really want to, you could do that in an extension method with a different name, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Side note: C# naming conventions frown on underscores; your variables should be called `lockFile` and `lockObj`.

Comment: Actually, if he really wanted to, he could inherit a class from SVNLock, call the Execute from its constructor and use this new class instead of SVNLock in his code.

Comment: +1 for recommending the Fluent Interface pattern. I'd never recommend calling new something().DoMethod() it just feels very wrong now if it's the fluid pattern it's fine IMO since you can always add a var infront of it later if you need the instance after DoMethod.